# Getting Null for .val()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have inputs and selects. For some reason, some of them are giving me a null. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        $('table').append('<tr>' +
                '<td><button class=\'save\'>Save</button></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'name\' id=\'companyName\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'currency\' id=\'currency\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'ISOCode\' id=\'ISOCode\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'CalcDeadLine\' id=\'CalcDeadLine\' /></td>' +
                '<td><select name=\'mealAlgorithm\' id=\'mealAlgorithm\'><option value="True">Yes</option><option value="False">No</option></select></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'breakfast\' id=\'breakfast\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'halfBoard\' id=\'halfBoard\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'fullBoard\' id=\'fullBoard\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'adminID\' id=\'adminID\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'language\' id=\'language\' /></td>' +
                '<td><input name=\'approvalcid\' id=\'cid\' /></td>' +
                '<td><select name=\'useSMS\' id=\'useSMS\'><option value="True">Yes</option><option value="False">No</option></select></td>' +
                '<td><select name=\'active\' id=\'active\'><option value="True">Yes</option><option value="False">No</option></select></td>');

        $('#add').hide();
    })
});

$(".save").live("click", function () {
    var name = $("#companyName").val();
    var currency = $("#currency").val();
    var isoCode = $("#ISOCode").val();
    var calcDeadLine = $("#CalcDeadLine").val();
    var mealAlgorithm = $("#mealAlgorithm").val();
    var noMeal = 111;
    var breakfast = $("#breakfast").val();
    var halfBoard = $("#halfBoard").val();
    var fullBoard = $("#fullBoard").val();
    var adminID = $("#adminID").val();
    var language = $("#language").val();
    var cid = $("#cid").val();
    var useSms = $("#useSMS").val();
    var active = $("#active").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveCompany", "Admin")',
        data: {
            "CompanyName": name, "Currency": currency, "ISOCompanyCode": isoCode, "CalcDeadline": calcDeadLine,
            "UseMealAlgorithm": mealAlgorithm, "NoMeal": noMeal, "Breakfast": breakfast, "HalfBoard": halfBoard,
            "FullBoard": fullBoard, "AdminUserID": adminID, "ApprovalCulture": language, "ApprovalLcid": cid,
            "UseSMS": useSms, "Active": active},
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result == true) {
                $("#GridCompany").html("Record has been saved!");
            }
            else {
                alert("There is some error.");
            }
        }
    })
})
```

In url of post everything is ok, it has true/false and every parameter with every value fulfilled.

In my controller I have

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SaveCompany(string name, string currency, string isoCode, int calcDeadline, bool? mealAlgorithm,
        int noMeal, int breakfast, int halfBoard, int fullBoard, string adminUserId, string approvalCulture,
        int? approvalCid, bool? useSms, bool? active)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            result = _companyRepository.SaveCompany(name, currency, isoCode, calcDeadline, mealAlgorithm, noMeal,
                breakfast, halfBoard, fullBoard, adminUserId, approvalCulture, approvalCid, useSms, active);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Nulls are isoCode, mealAlgorithm, approvalCid.

Comment: Eh... you are expecting to receive e.g. `isoCode` and you are sending `ISOCompanyCode`. The result shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: Is rigth @Jon, also UseMealAlgorithm ij jquery and mealAlgorithm in C#

Comment: Why are you `get`ing a save instead of `post`ing the data?  `get` is generally expected to be idempotent.

Comment: On the second click of "Add" you'll have duplicate id's. you'll only ever save the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the wrong names of the fields.
In the AJAX you pass `ISOCompanyCode` but in the Action you're waiting for `isoCode`
The same is for the other two fields (you have different names). Use the same names and it'll fix your problem.